# display(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'win'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ui, pyqt

Нужно, чтобы при нажимании кнопок на калькуляторе, значения выводились на экран по очереди, а не заменяли друг друга!

Вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from calc import Ui_MainWindow

class win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(win, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_3)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_4)
        self.ui.pushButton_6.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_5)
        self.ui.pushButton_7.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_6)
        self.ui.pushButton_8.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_7)
        self.ui.pushButton_9.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_8)
        self.ui.pushButton_10.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_9)
        self.ui.pushButton_11.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_10)
        self.ui.pushButton_12.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_11)
        self.ui.pushButton_13.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_12)
        self.ui.pushButton_14.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_13)
        self.ui.pushButton_15.pressed.connect(self.btnPressed_14)

        self.setWindowTitle('Калькулятор')

    def btnPressed(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(1))
    def btnPressed_1(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(2))
    def btnPressed_2(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(3))
    def btnPressed_3(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(4))
    def btnPressed_4(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(5))
    def btnPressed_5(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(6))
    def btnPressed_6(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(7))
    def btnPressed_7(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(8))
    def btnPressed_8(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(9))
    def btnPressed_9(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + '+')
    def btnPressed_10(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + float(0))
    def btnPressed_11(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + '-')
    def btnPressed_12(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + '*')
    def btnPressed_13(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display())
    def btnPressed_14(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.display() + ':')



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = win()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я пробовал что-то сделать, ничего не получалось, на данном этапе выдаёт такие ошибки

```
display(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'win'
  display(self, float): argument 1 has unexpected type 'win'
  display(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'win'
```

Что делать? Как сделать так, чтобы значения выводились друг за другом, а не заменяя друг друга

Comment: А если будет 100 кнопок, вы будете писать `btnPressed_100` ?) Вы серьезно? Самим не страшно? По поводу, того. что заменяется значение, так вы сами обновляете дисплей, а не продолжаете вывод...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так (также с остальными):

```
def btnPressed_9(self):
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display(self.ui.lcdNumber.value()+"+")
```

И еще: есть циклы, а имена классов пишутся с большой буквы.